# Does a material component cost for one component require all components involved for the spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components, spellcasting-focus

When a cost is listed for a component, does that mean you need all components to cast the spell or only the one with the cost included?

*Guards and wards*, page 248 PHB.

> burning incense, a small measure of brimstone and oil, a knotted string, a small amount of umber hulk blood, **and a small silver rod worth at least 10 gp**

Material (M), page 203 PHB.

> But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have that specific component before he or she can cast the spell.

Basically, can a focus be used to replace "*burning incense, a small measure of brimstone and oil, a knotted string, a small amount of umber hulk blood*" but not the "*small silver rod*"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## You only need to supply the material that has a cost

As you quote

> But if a cost is indicated for a component, a character must have **that specific component** before he or she can cast the spell.

If the intent was to have you be unable to replace *all* of the components with a focus, it would say "a character must have *all* the components for the spell" -- but it does not, it just says "that specific component." A spellcasting focus can replace all the other components as normal.

#### Some spells do require you to have all material components on hand

However, some spells indicate that all of the material components have a cost. In this case, you must provide all of the components. For example, the MC of *find familiar* is:

> 10gp worth of charcoal, incense, and herbs that must be consumed by fire in a brass brazier

The charcoal, incense, and herbs must cost 10gp altogether, and they must be consumed by fire in a brass brazier. A spellcasting focus cannot substitute for any of the components here because all the consumable parts also cost money, and they specify the manner in which they must be consumed.

*Divination* is another example, which requires:

> incense and a sacrificial offering appropriate to your religion, together worth at least 25 gp

#### Summary

In essence, the components you may not replace with a spellcasting focus are *only* those which have a gold cost, but all other materials can be substituted out as normal. However, some spells have material components which all share a cost, such as *find familiar* and *divination*. In these cases, you need to have all the components on hand.

Comment: Why does find familiar "indicate that all of the material components have a cost"? Couldn't strictly by RAW the brass brazier be replaced by a spellcasting focus? I don't see a cost indicated for the brass brazier.

Answer (score 4):

### Correct, specific components with costs must be supplied separately from the component pouch.

The rules cited in the question spell this out, and they are repeated in the equipment section:

> **Component Pouch.** A component pouch is a small, watertight leather belt pouch that has compartments to hold all the material components and other special items you need to cast your spells, except for those components that have a specific cost (as indicated in a spell's description).

(PHB, p.151).

*Guards and wards* is a great example of this, as spelled out in the question. Sometimes a spell has more than one component that has a cost; if so, it will be clearly stated; for example, the material component for *divination* is:

> incense and a sacrificial offering appropriate to your religion, **together worth** at least 25 gp.

(PHB p. 234, emphasis mine).